# Absorption Cross Section for Two-Level Spin System in an AC Magnetic Field - Photon Picture

Tags: photons, magnetic-moment, absorption, dipole-moment, two-level-system

For a two-level spin with a energy difference of $E = h f$, where the two levels have zero dipole electric coupling and can only be driven by a magnetic field, how do I calculate the absorption cross section and photon absorption rate in a uniform oscillating magnetic field at the transition frequency?

Do I need any further information beyond the spin transition frequency, and the detuning and amplitude of the oscillating magnetic field? Or are all such systems identical in their cross section?

Prior research: I found an expression that suggests that the stimulated transition rate (which seems relevant) goes as $(\lambda ^2 / 8 \pi) A_{21}$, but I'm uncertain how to calculate $A_{21}$ for this system. A lot of what I've found relates to magnetic coupling between a cavity mode and a spin, and involves an Einstein A coefficient involving a "g" coupling factor dependent on the geometric overlap between the cavity mode and the spin, but it seems to me that this is the wrong treatment for a uniform oscillating magnetic field with a spin.